# Returning unique() function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator, unique

I came across the following function, which sorts an array passed down by main(), removes duplicates, and returns the  number of unique elements. It's the last bit I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around.

```
int reduce(long ar[], int n) {
  sort(ar, ar + n);
  return unique(ar, ar + n) - ar; // ??? 
}
```

To my understanding unique() returns a pointer to the end of the segment that stores the  unique values in the array. But I don't see why subtracting the array name from the iterator results in an int that equals the number of unique elements, or why `unique(ar, ar+n)` can't be typecasted to int to achieve the same result.

Comment: I don't understand why if unique() return a pointer the function reduce return a int and not a int *.

Comment: @user1929959 Because what the return-statement evaluates to is not a pointer, but the _difference_ between two pointers.

Comment: So, your function return the difference between two memory addresses?

Comment: @user1929959 It's not my function, but yes, this is clearly the case.

Comment: @user1929959: The difference of two pointers into the same sequence is the number of elements in between.

Comment: Would be productive to see unique function from STL.

Comment: @user1929959 This _is_ the `unique` function from the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why unique(ar, ar+n) can't be typecasted to int to achieve the same result.

Because, as you said, `unique` returns a pointer.  A pointer is a memory address, not an index.  So casting a pointer to an int is meaningless.

> why subtracting the array name from the iterator results in an int that equals the number of unique elements

Subtracting two pointers (into the same array) evaluates to the number of elements between them.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* As pointed out by @Nawaz in comments below, this result is signed.  So `(p1 - p2) == -(p2 - p1)`.</sub>

Comment: @Nawaz: true!  I've attributed you in a footnote ;)

Answer (score 5):

Say you have an array like this:

```
{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5}
```

After calling `std::unique`, you'll probably end up with this (thank-you, Nawaz), with the elements past the new end left as they used to be before the call:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5}
               ^
```

`std::unique` returns an iterator to the new end of the array, so where the arrow is. From there it makes logical sense that subtracting the beginning of the array would return the number of unique elements. If you want to be a bit more explicit, you can use `return std::distance(ar, std::unique(ar, ar + n));`, which also works when the iterator doesn't support subtraction.

Comment: The processed array is wrong. `std::unique` doesn't swap duplicate elements with the elements after the *new* end. I mean, it may just return `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, | 4, 5}` where `|` marks the new end.

Comment: @Nawaz, I'll presume you meant `4, 2` at the end, but yeah, I wasn't sure exactly what it does with them, and figured those duplicates aren't useful for anything (at least here) anyway. It's up to the implementation as to what order the duplicates are in, isn't it? Either way, I'll make what I was trying to say in there a little more explicit.

Comment: @chris: The spec doesn't say anything about the elements after the new end, which *I think* means they *stay* there, as I've shown in the previous comment.

Comment: @Nawaz, Oh, I get what you mean now. It's consistent with cppreference's example. The description makes so much more sense now. I'm just being braindead from being tired.

Comment: @Nawaz, Thanks for sticking with me. It took me long enough to interpret what you were saying correctly, and from your side, it's kind of frustrating.